# Async file upload in IE 9 and 10 only

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, internet-explorer, file-upload

### Objective

I am creating a web application and have been looking for an async file upload solution other than iframe and form support.

### Browser Support

I am fully willing to exclude everything but IE9+.  IE tends to be the browser I have the most trouble with.

### Goal

I have a table and I want to be able to click on a link, show a file dialog and then upload the file immediately after selection.  No page refresh.

More specifically I am trying to figure out how [Trello](https://trello.com) does their file uploads.  After looking through the javascript, I found that they bind the the file input to an on change listener, but after that I can't see what they are doing.  Im under the impression that they use websockets with node.js to transfer data, but after doing a little research, most people say that websockets wouldn't be good for that.  Trello blocks all versions of IE except 9 and 10 so I looked into HTML5 File upload think that may be a solution.  However, after some research IE9 does not support the HTML5 File API.

### Question

So finally I am looking for some way to upload files without the iframe and form solution.  Can someone list the possible methods I could use?

### Sidenote

I am using Rails for backend and Ember.js for front end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the browser does not support the File API and XMLHttpRequest level 2, there is no other way to upload files in an async/"ajaxy" manner other than reverting to the hidden iframe method.  You could, of course, use Flash or Java, but neither of those (especially Java) seem like a good solution to me.

Regardless of the browser, you will have to include a file input element on the page if you want to provide a file chooser for the user.  The onchange listener you speak of is vital to determining when the user has actually selected a file or files.  In browsers that support the File API, you can also allow users to drop files they wish to upload onto your page.  This behavior alone does not require a file input element.

IE9 and older do not support the File API.

I'm quite familiar with this territory as I maintain a fairly popular javascript-only upload library: [Fine Uploader](http://fineuploader.com).